# trouble installing rPython

Tags: python, r

I tried to install rPython package in Linux system but I got following errors. I tried to search online but couldn't find a solution. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
> Sys.setenv(PATH = "/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/bin")
> system("python --version")
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

> install.packages('rPython')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/rPython_0.0-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 37138 bytes (36 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 36 KB

/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 8: uname: command not found
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 143: exec: sh: not found

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp8seq13/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rPython") :
installation of package ‘rPython’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing wrong with setting up env var `PATH`. It should be something equivalent with this shell command:

`$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/dir`